# Maven dependency of Apache Commons Imaging

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons

I need to access JPEG and TIFF metadata.

For this task, I'm trying to use Apache Commons Imaging library, which seems not to be available in Maven Central. How can I add this dependency?

Answer (score 3):

According to the readme at their github [repo](https://github.com/apache/commons-imaging)

> There is currently no stable release of Imaging. However you can pull
>   the latest SNAPSHOT from the Apache snapshot repository by adding the
>   snapshot repository to your pom.xml

The url for the snapshot is https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

Comment: Answering and voting to close is not very nice. It keeps other people from answering, thereby making sure your answer is the only one...

Comment: @Tunaki I feel the question is off-topic but I also happened to remember seeing a github repo about this project. I thought it might be helpful to the OP. Do you recommend I delete the answer ? The OP must have seen it by now.

Comment: I was just commenting of the fact that you answered while voting to close. Those two actions seems contradictory to me. (I don't recommend anything, it's your post and your vote, so your call).

Comment: Off-topic questions also have answers. I am sorry if I came out as not playing nice. I guess I should add something like that as a comment in the future.